# How to create dynamic label show by scrollview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uilabel

I tried show web service fields on some labels by select count.I am sorry my question is ver y large but I must solve this problem.

I have some labels.

Select "1" branch

```
                       Branch Name : XYZ Branch


                        Product1   Product2   Product3  Product4



   Sales Number        12        13         15           22


  Liters               123       132        111          231

  Price              123000     1243300    1929922       2232233
```

Select "2" branch

```
                       Branch Name : ABC Branch


                        Product1   Product2   Product3    Product4



   Sales Number        17           18             17      44  


  Liters               123          132            111     343

  Price                45454545     565656     34343434   2232323
```

Outputs are here

When select top 1 branch

[image]

When select  top 2 branch

[image]

My question :It show me one by one.When I select top 1.branch it show me top 1.branch details. I want when I select top 10 from count it will be show me top 10 branches details from web service under and under by scrollview like tableview.

```
      @interface ViewController ()

      {



   NSMutableData *webData;
   NSXMLParser *xmlParser;
   NSMutableString *retornoSOAP;
   BOOL teveRetorno;
   NSMutableString *retornoSOAP1;
   BOOL teveRetorno1;


  }

  - (void)selectAnElection:(NSNumber *)selectedIndex element:(id)element;
  - (void)selectProducts:(NSNumber *)selectedIndex element:(id)element;
  - (void)selectCount:(NSNumber *)selectedIndex element:(id)element;

   @end

   @synthesize elections = _elections;
   @synthesize products = _products;
  @synthesize topnumber = _topnumber;
  -(void)viewDidLoad
  {

  NSMutableArray* topnumbershow = [NSMutableArray new];

  self.elections= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"miktar", @"tutar", @"adet", nil];

  self.products = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"KB95", @"Motorin", @"LPG",@"Toplam", nil];

   for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
    [topnumbershow addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]];
   }

   self.topnumber= topnumbershow;
```

My picker buttons

```
   - (IBAction)selectAnElection:(UIControl *)sender {
  [ActionSheetStringPicker showPickerWithTitle:@"Choose a  election" rows:self.elections   
  initialSelection:self.selectedIndex target:self    
   successAction:@selector(selectAnElection:element:)   
   cancelAction:@selector(actionPickerCancelled:) origin:sender];

   }


  - (IBAction)selectProducts:(UIControl *)sender {
   [ActionSheetStringPicker showPickerWithTitle:@"Select a Products" rows:self.products 
   initialSelection:self.selectedIndex target:self 
   successAction:@selector(selectProducts:element:) 
    cancelAction:@selector(actionPickerCancelled:) origin:sender];
   }

  - (IBAction)selectCount:(UIControl *)sender {
  [ActionSheetStringPicker showPickerWithTitle:@"Top numbers ? " rows:self.topnumber
   initialSelection:self.selectedIndex target:self 
   successAction:@selector(selectCount:element:) 
   cancelAction:@selector(actionPickerCancelled:) origin:sender];

   }
```

Show details button

```
  -(IBAction) ShowDetails:(UIButton *)sender


  {
     NSString *mensagemSOAP= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" 

     encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                         "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-  
     instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"   
      xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
       "<soap:Body>\n"
        "<TopBranches xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
        "<date1>%@</date1>\n"
        "<date2>%@</date2>\n"
        "<Elections>%@</Elections>\n"
        "<Products>%@</Products>\n"
        "<Count>%@</Count>\n"
         "</TopBranches>\n"
          "</soap:Body>\n"
           "</soap:Envelope>\n",
         Date1.text,Date2.text,_ElectionsTextField.text,
      _ProductsTextfield.text,_CountTextField.text];




      NSLog(@"SOAP Message = \n%@\n\n", mensagemSOAP);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://webservice:1249/topbranchdetails.asmx"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];       
    NSString *tamanhoMensagem = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [mensagemSOAP length]];

   [theRequest addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
   [theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/TopBranches"  
   forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
   [theRequest addValue:tamanhoMensagem forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
   [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
   [theRequest setHTTPBody:[mensagemSOAP dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

     NSURLConnection *conexao = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest 
     delegate:self];

  if(conexao){
    webData = [NSMutableData data];
   }else{
    NSLog(@"Connection Error.");
   }
   }
```

XML Parsing Processes

```
  -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse  
  *)response{
[webData setLength: 0];
  }

  -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
   [webData appendData:data];
  }

  -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
  NSLog(@"Connection Error.");
  }

  -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
  NSLog(@"Bitti. Alinan Veri Byte: %d", [webData length]);
  NSString *xmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length: 
  [webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSLog(@"%@", xmlString);
  if (xmlParser) {
    xmlParser = nil;
}

xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:webData];
[xmlParser setDelegate:self];
[xmlParser shouldResolveExternalEntities];
[xmlParser parse];


  }

  int numberOfCount = 0;


  -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName               
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:      
  (NSDictionary *)attributeDict{


  if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"BranchName"] ) {



    if (!retornoSOAP) {
        retornoSOAP = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
    teveRetorno = YES;

}

if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"BranchID"] ) {



    if (!retornoSOAP) {
        retornoSOAP = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
    teveRetorno = YES;

}

if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"KB95Miktar"] ) {



    if (!retornoSOAP) {
        retornoSOAP = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
    teveRetorno = YES;

}


if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"MotorinMiktar"] ) {



    if (!retornoSOAP) {
        retornoSOAP = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
    teveRetorno = YES;

}





if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"LpgMiktar"] ) {



    if (!retornoSOAP) {
        retornoSOAP = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
    teveRetorno = YES;

}



if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"MiktarToplam"] ) {



    if (!retornoSOAP) {
        retornoSOAP = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
    teveRetorno = YES;

}


if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"KB95Adet"] ) {



    if (!retornoSOAP) {
        retornoSOAP = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
    teveRetorno = YES;

}


if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"MotorinAdet"] ) {



    if (!retornoSOAP) {
        retornoSOAP = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
    teveRetorno = YES;

}

if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"LpgAdet"] ) {



    if (!retornoSOAP) {
        retornoSOAP = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
    teveRetorno = YES;

}

if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"AdetToplam"] ) {



    if (!retornoSOAP) {
        retornoSOAP = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
    teveRetorno = YES;

}
if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"KB95Tutar"] ) {



    if (!retornoSOAP) {
        retornoSOAP = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
    teveRetorno = YES;

}
if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"MotorinTutar"] ) {



    if (!retornoSOAP) {
        retornoSOAP = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
    teveRetorno = YES;

}
if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"LpgTutar"] ) {



    if (!retornoSOAP) {
        retornoSOAP = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
    teveRetorno = YES;

}
  if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"TutarToplam"] ) {



    if (!retornoSOAP) {
        retornoSOAP = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
    teveRetorno = YES;

}

  }

  - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
 if (teveRetorno) {
    [retornoSOAP appendString:string];
 }
  }
```

Display web service fields on labels

```
  - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
   namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{



if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"BranchName"] ) {
   BranchName.text = retornoSOAP;

    retornoSOAP = nil;
    teveRetorno = NO;



}

  if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"BranchID"] ) {
    BranchID.text = retornoSOAP;

    retornoSOAP = nil;
    teveRetorno = NO;

}


 if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"KB95Miktar"] ) {
    K95MiktarLabel.text = retornoSOAP;

    retornoSOAP = nil;
    teveRetorno = NO;

}

 if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"MotorinMiktar"] ) {
    MotorinMiktarLabel.text = retornoSOAP;

    retornoSOAP = nil;
    teveRetorno = NO;

}
if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"LpgMiktar"] ) {
    LPGMiktarLabel.text = retornoSOAP;

    retornoSOAP = nil;
    teveRetorno = NO;

}
if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"MiktarToplam"] ) {
    ToplamMiktarLabel.text = retornoSOAP;

    retornoSOAP = nil;
    teveRetorno = NO;

}
if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"KB95Tutar"] ) {
    K95TutarLabel.text = retornoSOAP;

    retornoSOAP = nil;
    teveRetorno = NO;

}
if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"MotorinTutar"] ) {
    MotorinTutarLabel.text = retornoSOAP;

    retornoSOAP = nil;
    teveRetorno = NO;

}
if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"LpgTutar"] ) {
    LPGTutarLabel.text = retornoSOAP;

    retornoSOAP = nil;
    teveRetorno = NO;

}
if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"TutarToplam"] ) {
    ToplamTutarLabel.text = retornoSOAP;

    retornoSOAP = nil;
    teveRetorno = NO;

}

if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"KB95Adet"] ) {
    K95AdetLabel.text = retornoSOAP;

    retornoSOAP = nil;
    teveRetorno = NO;

}
if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"MotorinAdet"] ) {
    MotorinAdetLabel.text = retornoSOAP;

    retornoSOAP = nil;
    teveRetorno = NO;

}

if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"LpgAdet"] ) {
    LPGAdetLabel.text = retornoSOAP;

    retornoSOAP = nil;
    teveRetorno = NO;

}

if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"AdetToplam"] ) {
    ToplamAdetLabel.text = retornoSOAP;

    retornoSOAP = nil;
    teveRetorno = NO;

}

 }



  - (void)selectAnElection:(NSNumber *)selectedIndex element:(id)element {
  self.selectedIndex = [selectedIndex intValue];

//may have originated from textField or barButtonItem, use an IBOutlet instead of element
 self.ElectionsTextField.text = [self.elections objectAtIndex:self.selectedIndex];

}

  - (void)selectProducts:(NSNumber *)selectedIndex element:(id)element {
self.selectedIndex = [selectedIndex intValue];

//may have originated from textField or barButtonItem, use an IBOutlet instead of element
self.ProductsTextfield.text = [self.products objectAtIndex:self.selectedIndex];
}


  - (void)selectCount:(NSNumber *)selectedIndex element:(id)element {
self.selectedIndex = [selectedIndex intValue];

//may have originated from textField or barButtonItem, use an IBOutlet instead of element
self.CountTextfield.text = [self.topnumber objectAtIndex:self.selectedIndex];
  }
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You wanna show top 10 results in scrollview or tableview?

Comment: @HinataHyuga Yes I want this.I can show one by one but I want show top 10 or top selected number.

Comment: then use uitableview with custom cell.

Comment: @HinataHyuga I tried but I have failed.For that I used labels.

Comment: are you adding uilabel dynamically or you are simply making hidden property true or false? is there any limit for records ? or they can select as many as they want?

Comment: You pasted whole project :D

Comment: @HinataHyuga hidden property true in button click.

Comment: @MehmetAkyel As I understood your question you are supposed to show details of each branch when you select that branch. And when you select multiple branch then the details for each branch should be displayed in tableview or scroll view. As per output in your question it would be better to use scroll view. You can use one view with all details (as shown in question) and then you can add that view multiple times (= number of branches you want to show) in scroll view.

Comment: @TheTiger this is small part of project :)

Comment: @KmlHarariyA Yes you are right :) How you can help me ? :)

Comment: @MehmetAkyel If you are getting the response for all 10 branches in one shot, then you might will get 10 objects in response. You can show one objects details in one UIView object and then add that view in scroll view and same for all other 9. You need to increase the content size of scroll view as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this.

```
[self createDynamicView];
```

---

```
-(void)createDynamicView{

    CGFloat yOffset = 0;

    for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {  //how many views you want to add in scrollview
        yOffset += 5;
        UILabel* lblHeaderTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, yOffset, 310, 21)];
        [lblHeaderTitle setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
        [lblHeaderTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:16.0f]];
        [lblHeaderTitle setText:[currentDict valueForKey:@"TITLE"]];
        [lblHeaderTitle setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];


        [scrlvDynamicContent addSubview:lblHeaderTitle];
        [lblHeaderTitle release];
        //INCREMNET in yOffset 
        yOffset += 25;

    [scrlvDynamicContent setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, yOffset)];

}
```